# Marshall an array of structs

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling

I am calling a C++ function from C#. As arguments it receives a pointer to an array of structs.

```
struct A 
{
    int data;
}

int CFunction (A* pointerToFirstElementOfArray, int NumberOfArrayElements)
```

In C# I have created the same struct (as a class) and I marshall it correctly (the first element in the array is received correctly). Here is my C# definition of the C++ struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), Serializable]
class A
{
    int data;
}
```

The first element is read correctly so I know all the fields in the struct are marshalled correctly. The problem occurs when I try to send over an array of elements. **How do I create an array of classes that will be in a single memory block (chunk), so the C++ function can increment the pointer to the array?**

I guess I would need something similar to stackalloc, however I belive that only works for primitive types?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know the size of the array you're sending at compile time ?

Comment: @ohadsc No, its a length of an array (different array), it is only known at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended to be a definitive answer, but merely an example of you could accomplish this using `stackalloc` and unsafe code.

```
public unsafe class Example
{
  [DllImport("library.dll")]
  private static extern int CFunction(A* pointerToFirstElementOfArray, int NumberOfArrayElements); 

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    A* a = stackalloc A[LENGTH];
    CFunction(a, LENGTH);
  }
}
```

Also, pay attention to the packing of the struct that the API accepts. You may have to play around with the `Pack` property of the `StructLayout` attribute. I believe the default is 4, but some APIs expect 1.

**Edit:**

For this to work you will have to change the declaration of `A` from a class to a struct.

```
public struct A
{
  public int data;
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: _Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('A')_

Comment: @Rekreativc: That's odd. I tested the code before I posted it. I actually use this approach in some of my code and it works fine. There must be something else going on.